# Enabling restrictions for camera in iPad throws NSException while opening camera

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, camera, settings, nsexception

I've enabled the restrictions and disallowed the camera and FaceTime in the settings of iPad and in the privacy tab, I disabled the access to photos for my application.

I'm opening the camera and photo library using below code,

```
//For camera
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];

//For Photo library
UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
picker.delegate = self;
picker.allowsEditing = NO;
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

While opening the photo library, it clearly displays a message that the access is denied and it can be changed in the settings app. But while opening camera, the app crashes throwing the error,

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Source type 1 not available'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30584f4b 0x3ac566af 0x32f56d69 0x1141d9 0x32ee4d03 0x32d2c713 0x32d2c6b3 0x32d2c691 0x32d1811f 0x32d2c107 0x32d2bdd9 0x32d26e65 0x32cfc79d 0x32cfafa3 0x30550183 0x3054f653 0x3054de47 0x304b8c27 0x304b8a0b 0x3518c283 0x32d5c049 0xeff7d 0x3b15eab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always check wether a source type is available:

**From the Apple [`UIImagePickerController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html) doucmentatiom**

> Verify that the device is capable of picking content from the desired
>   source. Do this calling the [`isSourceTypeAvailable:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImagePickerController/isSourceTypeAvailable%3a) class method,
>   providing a constant from the `UIImagePickerControllerSourceType`
>   enumeration.

Check wether the source is available like:

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
 // UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary is available.
}
```